# Using StackExchange.Redis in a ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, redis

I'd like to use Redis features such as bitfields and hashfields from an MVC controller. I understand there's [built in caching support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed) in ASP.NET core but this only supports basic GET and SET commands, not the commands that I need in my application. I know how to use StackExchange.Redis from a normal (eg. console) application, but I'm not sure how to set it up in an ASP site.

Where should I put all the connection initialization code so that I can have access to it afterwards from a controller? Is this something I would use dependency injection for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This blog](https://garywoodfine.com/why-when-and-how-to-use-redis-in-asp-net-mvc-core/) has a writeup (with accompanying [full code repo](https://github.com/garywoodfine/redis-mvc-core)) about implementing a redis service into ASP.NET Core. It has a boilerplate service that automatically serialises POCO classes into a redis hashset.

Answer (score 48):

In your Startup class's ConfigureServices method, you'll want to add:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("yourConnectionString"));
```

You can then use the dependency injection by changing your constructor signature to something like this:

```cs
public YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;
    public YourController(IConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer)
    {
        this._connectionMultiplexer = multiplexer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very simple solution

Answer (score 4):

The simple way is to install the Nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
```

in your ASP MVC .NET Core project.

Then configure the service with dependency injection in your class Startup in the method ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
        {
            option.Configuration = Configuration["AzureCache:ConnectionString"];
            option.InstanceName = "master";
        });
```

Add the binding connection string in the appsettings.json for release deployment like this:

```
"AzureCache": {
    "ConnectionString": "" 
  }
```

If you use Azure, add in the App setting name in Application Settings for your ASP MVC .NET Core App Service to bind at run-time on the Azure side after deployment. The connection string for production shouldn't occur in your code from the security reasons.

[Azure binding connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US8tn.png)

Add the binding for e.g. development appsettings.Development.json

```
"AzureCache": {
    "ConnectionString": "<your connection string>"
  }
```

Inject the service to your controller in the constructor:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
        public SomeController(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
```

Comment: This looks pretty and all, but keep in mind that this only implements a `IDistributedCache` which is a very limited implementation of Redis. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use username/password in the configuration

```
//StackExchange.Redis for configuration options
 var redisConfiguration = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints = { "serverinfo:portinfo" },
                User = username,
                Password = password
                //,Ssl = true
            };


            services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => { options.ConfigurationOptions = redisConfiguration; });
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not usually considered a good practice to store a username and password in clear text directly in your code, and especially if your code is (hopefully!) managed via source control, as that opens up a potential vulnerability in case your code is compromised. The previous [answer from @Ondrej-Rozinek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004428/3025856) addresses this by instead storing the credentials in a separate configuration file—which could be a `secrets.json` locally, an environment variable on a server, or any other configuration provider supported by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Yes, its good to store encrypted credentials in separate file. I was mentioning user username/password key pair.

Redis ACL has option to encrypt password and all the configuration:)
Its best practice to use username/password With ssl enable instead just having server and password or default user.

Comment: Aha, I see what you're saying. Thank you for clarifying that.