# Timeout performing SET (5000ms), but no Errors in redis.log or busy worker

Tags: c#, redis, .net-6.0, stackexchange.redis

I am new in Stackoverflow and I am asking this because I am confused, I have a .NET 6 Application which stores Key in Redis on-premise running at Rocky Linux 8.8 OS using the `StackExchange.Redis 2.2.4` library, at certain intervals, I got the following Error:

```
Timeout performing SET (5000ms), next: SET testKey, 
inst: 7, qu: 0, qs: 894, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync,
 ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, 
serverEndpoint: <My Redis Server>, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, 
clientName: <My Client Name>, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=47,Free=32720,Min=800,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433 
(Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

I'm sorry if I understand this wrong, but as far as I can see, the `qs` indicates that there are a lot of other operations awaiting reply from the redis worker, but the `WORKER` only shows 47 out of them being used.

Furthermore, this happens at certain interval only, I have set Azure Application Insight on my .NET Application and found the following:
[Azure Application Insight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMgPZ.png)

I have checked the `/etc/redis` log file with debug information and it reports no Error at all.

```
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:21.285 . 24 clients connected (0 replicas), 24262392 bytes in use
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:26.303 - DB 0: 2 keys (2 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:26.304 - DB 2: 380 keys (324 volatile) in 512 slots HT.
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:26.304 . 24 clients connected (0 replicas), 24221448 bytes in use
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:31.323 - DB 0: 2 keys (2 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:31.323 - DB 2: 378 keys (322 volatile) in 512 slots HT.
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:31.323 . 24 clients connected (0 replicas), 24220936 bytes in use
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.041 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.047 * Background saving started by pid 24143
24143:C 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.051 - Fork CoW for RDB: current 0 MB, peak 0 MB, average 0 MB
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.348 - DB 0: 2 keys (2 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.349 - DB 2: 378 keys (322 volatile) in 512 slots HT.
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.349 . 24 clients connected (0 replicas), 24220936 bytes in use
24143:C 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.349 * DB saved on disk
24143:C 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.350 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 6 MB, peak 6 MB, average 3 MB
21675:M 19 Oct 2023 18:42:36.449 * Background saving terminated with success
```

Furthermore, I have checked the server that hosted the Redis cache, I checked both CPU and disk usage when this occurs, and nothing is out of the ordinary. The CPU stays at below 30% of maximum load at most, and disk usage is only 13%.

This is the constructor of the Redis instance in the application, I re-used the same instance for the entire application:

```
 try
            {
                var connections = RedisConnectionFactory.GetConnections();
                foreach (var connection in connections)
                {
                    Database = connection.GetDatabase(2);
                    var endpoints = connection.GetEndPoints();
                    Server = connection.GetServer(endpoints.First());

                    // Test connection
                    try
                    {
                        SetKeyStringValue("testKey", "testValue", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        break;
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            catch { }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Are you doing Dependency injection of the `IConnectionMultiplexer` and preferably as a [Singleton](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-core-depedency-inject-with-real-use-case/)?

Comment: No, I used a static object of ConnectionMultiplexer and use `Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options));`. This `ConnectionMultiplexer` is then used for my application using `public static List<ConnectionMultiplexer> GetConnections() => Connections;` where there can be multiple `ConnectionMultiplexer` (of a single instance of `RedisFactory`) that each client can connect to one of the `ConnectionMultiplexer`

Comment: Let the DI Container handle your connection to Redis. [IConnectionMultiplexer as Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653358/7450780).

Comment: May I ask why should I use Singleton pattern for the `ConnectionMultiplexer`? How will it affect my application's connection to Redis? will it still creates multiple `ConnectionMultiplexer` so many clients can connect at once? Sorry if I'm wrong, in the meantime, I will try your solution.

Comment: With Singleton only one instance of  `IConnectionMultiplexer` is created and shared  throughout the app's lifetime (the same instance is used for all requests to your application). In .Net Core there are  [three service lifetimes](https://dotnetcorecentral.com/blog/service-lifetime/) to use when registering a service.

Comment: Okay for now I am trying to use DI for the `ConnectionMultiplexer` only, since the application is already in use and refactoring the `RedisFactory` using `IConnectionMultiplexer` might break a lot of things. Thanks for your suggestion! I'll post you updates after.